# Copying a range of cells in a column in one sheet to specified cells in a row in another

Tags: vba, excel

I've been doing a lot of surfing around for answers but I'm so green when it comes to writing VB code that I need specific help on how to write the code in my case. None of my copy&paste adventures have worked, so I'm hoping you'll be patient with me.

The current code I have is this:

```
    Sub CopyPaste()

Dim targetRng As Excel.Range
Dim destRng As Excel.Range
Set targetRng = Range("K6:K14,K19:K20")

With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    Set destRng = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Resize(targetRng.Rows.Count, targetRng.Columns.Count)
    destRng.Value = targetRng.Value
End With

With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")
Range("J6:J14,J19:J20").ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

... which works well, except that I want to post the data in a row, rather than in a column. (NB It's correct that the target range to copy is column K and the range to clear is J - as column J has drop-down lists to select from)

So I've sussed out that the bit of code I need to add is:

```
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out how or where to get that in there, and all the errors I'm getting are doing my head in.

Also, the data I am copying out is a range with a gap (K6:K14,K19:K20)- but the second range (K19:K20) doesn't paste into the 'Database' sheet. The .ClearContents function works fine for both sets in the range in column J, so I'm not seeing where I'm going wrong with that one either.

Take pity on the code noob?

Comment: So you're copying data, `K6:K14`, and want to paste that info *across* a row? You're going to need to use `.Copy`/`.PasteSpecial`.  Currently you are setting the range values equal, which is an efficient way of copying data only, so kudos on that!  However, replace the `destRng.Value` line with `targetRng.Copy` then next line `destRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True`.  That *might* throw an error since you have two ranges in `targetRng`, but maybe not...can't recall off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do doesn't seem to work on multiple selections. Unfortunately the debug information in VBA isn't the best so I tend to put some error handling in to make it a little more informative.

```
Sub Test()

On Error GoTo err_handler

    Dim copyRange As Excel.Range
    Set copyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10,A13:A14")
    Dim pasteRange As Excel.Range
    Set pasteRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:L1,O1:P1")

    copyRange.Copy
    pasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

    Exit Sub

err_handler:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)

End Sub
```

When this code is run and the error caught I see the following message

> This action won't work on multiple selections

If I split the ranges out like the following then it works as expected.

```
Sub Test()

On Error GoTo err_handler

    Dim copyRange As Excel.Range
    Set copyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
    Dim pasteRange As Excel.Range
    Set pasteRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:L1")

    copyRange.Copy
    pasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

    Set copyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A13:A14")
    Set pasteRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O1:P1")

    copyRange.Copy
    pasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

    Exit Sub

err_handler:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)

End Sub
```

I hope this helps.

Cheers Chris